# org.json.JSONException when trying to parse complex JSON subsection

Tags: java, json, java-8

Am facing impediments when using Java 1.8 and the `org.json` lib to marshal & parse a complex JSON object...

JSON dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>NOT_KNOWN</version>
</dependency>
```

---

JSON response payload:

```
{
    "products": {
        "productTypes": {
            "storeId": "abc123"
            "names": [
                "sku": "123",
                "prices": {
                    "salesTax": .2,
                    "wholeSalePrice": 5,
                    "retailPrice": 10
                }
            ]

        }
    }
}
```

---

```
// After obtaining as a jsonString
JSONObject productsJsonObject = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(jsonString).nextValue();

// This logs the correct the JSON listed above
logger.info("productsJsonObject = {}", productsJsonObject); 

// Exception happens here:
JSONObject productTypeJsonSection = (JSONObject) productsJsonObject.get("productTypes");
```

This exception is thrown:

```
org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["productTypes"] not found.
        at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:422) ~[json-NOT_KNOWN.jar:?]
```

Comment: Please share an [mcve]

Comment: Isn't this minimal enough? I posted three lines of code..  I am confused?

Comment: The object named `productsJsonObject` is actually the top level object that contains the `products` object. You need to  `.get(“products”)` on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, when I ran your code on the JSON string in your question, I got an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: Expected a ',' or ']' at 128 [character 26 line 6]
```

As @TimMoore wrote in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76652657/org-json-jsonexception-when-trying-to-parse-complex-json-subsection#comment135145270_76652657):

> The object named `productsJsonObject` is actually the top level object that contains the products object.

You have an unnamed JSON object that contains a single member named *products*. Hence after you do this:

```java
JSONObject productsJsonObject = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(jsonString).nextValue();
```

you need to do this:

```java
productsJsonObject = (JSONObject) productsJsonObject.get("products");
```

Then you can do this:

```java
JSONObject productTypesJsonObject = (JSONObject) productsJsonObject.get("productTypes");
```

Here is a complete example – including changes I made to the JSON string in order to overcome the exception, above.

Note that the code uses [text blocks](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/text-blocks/index.html) which were first added in JDK 15.

```java
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONTokener;

public class OrgJsonT {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String json = """
{
    "products": {
        "productTypes": {
            "storeId": "abc123",
            "names": [
                {
                    "sku": 123
                },
                {
                    "prices": {
                        "salesTax": .2,
                        "wholeSalePrice": 5,
                        "retailPrice": 10
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
                """;
        JSONTokener jsonTokener = new JSONTokener(json);
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonTokener.nextValue();
        JSONObject productsJsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("products");
        JSONObject productTypesJsonObject = (JSONObject) productsJsonObject.get("productTypes");
        System.out.println(productTypesJsonObject);
    }
}
```

Running the above code prints the following:

```
{"names":[{"sku":123},{"prices":{"wholeSalePrice":5,"salesTax":".2","retailPrice":10}}],"storeId":"abc123"}
```